# Trim whitespace from Windows shell command result

Tags: windows, shell

I'm trying to write a quick batch file. It will take the result of a command, put some extra text and quotes around it, and put that into a new file.The problem is that the result of the command I'm running includes a new line. Here's the command:

```
p4 changelists -m 1 -t //depot/...> %FILENAME%
```

The output of that `p4` command has a newline at the end of it. The file I'm putting it into needs to have quotes surrounding the output of that command, but the fact that the command contains a newline in it means that the "closing quote" appears on a new line in the file, which doesn't work for what I'm doing.

I've tried writing the output of that command into a file and reading it back in, and also trying to run `FINDSTR` on a file containing the output, but I always seem to get back the stupid trailing whitespace. I've even tried inserting backspaces into the file, but that just put a backspace character into the file instead of actually executing a backspace...

Is there anything to be done about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no perl wizard, but the following seems to work:

`p4 changelists -m 1 -t //depot/...| perl -p -e "s/^/\042/;s/$/\042/"`

Check out [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), which provides a Windows version of Perl.

I'm always looking at my Unix tools when solving problems like this, even under Windows.  sed and gawk will also get you there, check out [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) for a nice bundle of Unix tools that will run on Windows.

Comment: I like your idea of just biting the bullet and using Unix tools inside of Windows. I was trying to be a baller and do everything with native Windows shell commands, but it seems like more trouble than it's worth!